# split dirname year

Tags: regex, tcl

who can splitt this to variables? for Name and year
dirname and year set to a new variable

From :
!name England.london.2016.Camcorder.mkv

To:
dirname England.london
year 2016

From :
!name England.london.welsh.2016.Canon.jpg

To :
dirname England.london.welsh
year 2016

From :
!name Finnland.Helsinki.1999.Samsung.iphone.jpg

To :
dirname Finnland.Helsinki
year 1999

From :
!name Finnland.1999.Camcorder.mkv

To :
dirname Finnland
year 1999

```
bind pub "-|-" !name dirs 
proc dirs { nick uhost hand chan text} {

set name [lindex $text 0]

putnow "PRIVMSG $chan :dirname $dirname year $year"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
% #The format reference used is as follows, 
% # 'anytexthere.year.fewmoretexthere'
% proc parse_info {input} {
        set dirname {}
        set year {}
        regexp {^(.*)\.(\d{4})\..*$} $input match dirname year
        return [list $dirname $year]
}
%
% parse_info England.london.2016.Camcorder.mkv
England.london 2016
% parse_info incorrect.film_without.correct-format.mkv
{} {}
% parse_info England.london.welsh.2016.Canon.jpg
England.london.welsh 2016
% parse_info Finnland.Helsinki.1999.Samsung.iphone.jpg
Finnland.Helsinki 1999
% #film name containing numbers in it
% parse_info 1408.2007.Canon.mkv
1408 2007
%
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set data {
    England.london.2016.Camcorder.mkv
    England.london.welsh.2016.Canon.jpg
    Finnland.Helsinki.1999.Samsung.iphone.jpg
    Finnland.1999.Camcorder.mkv
}

foreach line [split [string trim $data] \n] {
    set dirname {}
    foreach word [split [string trim $line] .] {
        if {[string is digit -strict $word]} {
            break
        } else {
            lappend dirname $word
        }
    }
    puts "dirname [join $dirname .] year $word"
}
```

This one splits the data into lines, and the lines into words. For each line, it collects words for the dirname until it finds a word with nothing but digits in it, and then prints out what it’s got.

Another way, matching a regular expression against each line:

```
foreach {- dirname year} [regexp -all -inline -line {^\s*([^\d]*)(\d{4})} $data] {
    puts "dirname [string trimright $dirname .] year $year"
}
```

Documentation:
[break](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/break.htm),
[foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm),
[if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm),
[join](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/join.htm),
[lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm),
[puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm),
[regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm),
[string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm),
[Syntax of Tcl regular expressions](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm)